# Implementing OnCheckedChanged in Java

Tags: java, android, events, oncheckedchanged

Basically in one fragment, I have 3 toggle buttons, therefore I decided that my interface should implement OnCheckedChange. These buttons are : `date` button, `time` button and `now` button.

The work flow would be the following:

`date` is pressed, date image is changed to being active, check if `time` is pressed, check `mark` is active
`time` is pressed, date image is changed to being active, check if `date` is pressed, check `mark` is active

`now` is pressed, `date` and `time` won't be active but check mark will. What I've done is the following:

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        switch (buttonView.getId()) {
        case R.id.select_date_button: {
            DialogFragment datePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
            datePicker.setTargetFragment(CheckinNow.this, 100);
            datePicker.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
            date_image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_calendar_active);

            break;
        }

        case R.id.select_time_button: {
            DialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment();
            timePicker.setTargetFragment(CheckinNow.this, 100);
            timePicker.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
            time_image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_time_active);

        }

        case R.id.now_button: {
            now_button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_now_with_text_active);
            checkin_button_done.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_checkmark_active);
            time_image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_time);
            date_image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_calendar);

        }

        default:
            break;
    }
```

My question is how can I check when `date` is pressed and `time` as well or the other way around?

I can, of course, set an `OnCheckedChanged` for each button individually, but I'd prefer this solution if possible.

Comment: You can use getActivity() to access parent methods on your activity. Fragments can't see each other, so having some booleans and methods on your activity should allow them to interact safely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about storing your Buttons with

```
ToggleButton dateButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.select_date_button);
```

Then if you need to check if one button is checked or not, just call

```
if (dateButton.isChecked()) {
//Do some stuff
}
```

Hope this helps!